# change linux error message language

Tags: centos

My machine is running centos 6.0. The problem is that It displays error message in unrecognized chinese(I do read chinese however the message is not readable). It doesn't always gives message in chinese.

for example, running a non-existing command in terminal still gives me english error. however, If i am connecting via ftp then the welcome message is in chinese, unrecognized again.

I am not familiar with centos and not the one setup the box.. but /etc/sysconfig/i18n has the following content:

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
SYSFONT="latarcyrheb-sun16"
```

Now How do I make this box behaves in english? :)

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running

```
system-config-language
```

You might have to install the rpm if it isn't installed